# Knockout: model not updated in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, knockout.js, compatibility, custom-binding

We have a weird issue that's happening only in **Internet Explorer**. The feature is working on Firefox and on Chrome.
The bug can be reproduced in knockout 2.2.1 and in knockout 3.1.0.

I have spans that change them self to a textboxes when double clicked.

Here's the html:

```
<div>
    <span class="dataSourceSpan">@resourceManager.GetString("STR_DATABASE_SCHEMA_NAME"):</span>
    <div class="SchemasBloc">
        <ul class="Schemas" data-bind="sortable: { data: SchemaList, afterMove: UpdateDatabaseSchemaNameFromList }, visible: SchemaList().length > 0 ">
            <li class="SchemaList" data-bind="css: { selected: $data == $parent.SelectedSchema() }, click: $parent.SetSelectedSchema">
                <span class="labelText" data-bind="text: Description, visible: !isEditing(), event: { dblclick: startEdit }"></span>
                <input class="SchemaInput" data-bind="value: Description, visible: isEditing(), hasFocus: isEditing(), event: { keyup: endEditEnter, blur: endEdit }" />
                <a class="k-button" title="@resourceManager.GetString("STR_REMOVE_SCHEMA")" data-bind="click: $parent.removeSelectedSchema"><span class="k-icon k-i-close"></span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <span class="addSchema">
            <a class="k-button" data-bind="click: AddSchema" title="@resourceManager.GetString("STR_ADD_SCHEMA")"><span class="k-icon k-i-plus"></span></a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
var ShemaModel = function (description, IsNew) {
    var self = this;

    self.Description = ko.observable(description);
    self.IsNew = ko.observable(IsNew);

    self.isEditing = ko.observable(false);
    self.TemporaryEnvironmentDescription = ko.observable(false);


    self.startEdit = function (model, event) {
        self.isEditing(true);
        self.TemporaryEnvironmentDescription(self.Description());
        $(".Schemas .selected").children("input").focus();
    };

    self.endEdit = function (model, event) {
        if (self.Description() !== self.TemporaryEnvironmentDescription() && self.Description() !== "" && self.isEditing()) {
            self.TemporaryEnvironmentDescription(self.Description());
        }
        else if (self.IsNew() && self.isEditing()) {
            //remove the added schema
            environmentModel.SelectedEnvironment().SelectedDataSource().SchemaList.remove(environmentModel.SelectedEnvironment().SelectedDataSource().SelectedSchema());
        }
        environmentModel.SelectedEnvironment().SelectedDataSource().UpdateDatabaseSchemaNameFromList();
        self.isEditing(false);
        self.IsNew(false);
    };

    self.endEditEnter = function (Model, event) {
        event.keyCode === 13 && self.endEdit(Model, event);
    };
};
```

The problem in IE is in the `endEdit()` function `self.Description()` always return empty string. The model is not updated. Before editing, we store the `span` text value in a temp value. When the event `endedit` is triggered, we compare the temp value with the current value. If they are different we update the model.

When we hit the enter button the model is not updated (`keyUp` event is not working properly). The blur event is working fine. I don't know if it's related to the enter event that's not triggered.

I tried to force the blur event but it messed up my logic.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you verified that you are not getting any errors in the console?

Comment: There's no error at all in the console. I think, it something related with IE that's not triggering the event. Maybe knockout's model is updated only if that event is triggered...

Comment: Can you put together a SO snippet or fiddle that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding **valueUpdate: 'keyup'** in

```
<input class="SchemaInput" data-bind="value: Description, visible: isEditing(), hasFocus: isEditing(), event: { keyup: endEditEnter, blur: endEdit }" />
```

This will force the binding to update the value of Description observable on key release